# ng2-file-upload doesn't work when I do not have office installed

Tags: angularjs, ng2-file-upload

I tested the ng2-file-upload on my vm without any office installed, and I am trying to upload a file with a file type of .doc & .docx and it keeps me going to this condition ->

this.uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = (item, filter, options) => { }

is there a workaround on this to work without me having to install office at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your OS doesn't have any predefined specific `mime` type. It doesn't know how to open .docx/.xlsx/.ppt files. These mime types will be added to your OS with special soft.

Browser sets `application/octet-stream` as mime type of your file

So, your `back-end` should have two different scenarios on file-upload, where it should check `mime` type or file extension